# Cycling images in a live tile

Tags: visual-studio-2012, winjs

I have a **winJS** app that is a working launcher for a steam game. I'd like to get it to cycle through 5 images even while not running.

It uses *only* the small tile — there are no wide tiles images for this app.

Here's the code:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.Namespace.define("Steam", {
    launch: function launch(url) {
        var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(url);

        Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri).then(
             function (success) {
                 if (success) {
                     // File launched
                     window.close();
                 } else {
                     // File launch failed
                 }
             }
        );
    }
});

WinJS.Namespace.define("Tile", { 
    enqueue: function initialize() {
        var updaterHandle = Windows.UI.Notifications.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication();
        updaterHandle.enableNotificationQueue(true);
        return updaterHandle;
    },
    update: function update () {
        var template = Windows.UI.Notifications.TileTemplateType.tileSquareImage;
        var tileXml = Windows.UI.Notifications.TileUpdateManager.getTemplateContent(template);

        var randIndx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        var randUpdatetime = 1000 * 3 * (((randIndx == 0) ? 1 : 0) + 1); // let the base image stay longer

        var tileImageAttributes = tileXml.getElementsByTagName("image");

        tileImageAttributes[0].setAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///images/Borderlands2/borderlands_2_" + randIndx + "_sidyseven.png");
        tileImageAttributes[0].setAttribute("alt", "Borderlands 2");

        var tileNotification = new Windows.UI.Notifications.TileNotification(tileXml);
        var currentTime = new Date();

        tileNotification.expirationTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + randUpdatetime);
        tileNotification.tag = "newTile";

        var updater = Tile.enqueue();
        updater.update(tileNotification);

        setTimeout('Tile.update();', randUpdatetime);
    }
});


WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {                 
        setTimeout('Steam.launch("steam://rungameid/49520");', 800);
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
            return WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/default.html", args).then(function () {
                Tile.update();
            });
        }));
    }
};

app.start();
})();
```

Notes:

- The code currently does not cycle the image, instead either
  apparently never changing, or after launch replacing the *application
  name* text with a tiny view of the default image. This reverts to the
  text after a short time, and the cycle may repeat. It never shows a
  different image (neither in the small image it erroneously shows, nor
  in the main tile).
- When I run in debug and set a breakpoint at the
  `TileUpdater.update(TileNotification)` stage, I can verify in the
  console that the image **src** attribute is set to a random image
  just as I wanted:

  `>>>>tileNotification.content.getElementsByTagName("image")[0].getAttribute("src")`

  `"ms-appx:///images/Borderlands2/borderlands_2_4_sidyseven.png"`

  But this never actually displays on the tile.
- These image files are included in the solution, and they appear in the proper directory in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: long time to go without getting an answer that actually pertains to visual studio 2012 — I even offered bounty on this. someone answer it who has visual studio 2012/win8!

Answer (score 0):

If the image src attribute is set properly in debug then the image may not have the proper "Build Action".

In the 'Properties' of each image, set "Build Action" to "Resource".

[image]

Comment: My window for properties doesn't look like yours. There is no "advanced" nor "build action" in the right-click properties dialog (the tree on the left shows Configuration Properties->File Properties, but there it lacks the options)